# Перенос текста с одного поля ввода в другое (JS)

Tags: javascript

Всем привет, нужна помощь, как мне в моём коде при нажатии на кнопку сделать 
так, чтобы текст из textarea с id txt1 переходил в textarea с id txt2

```
<textarea id="txt1" class="txt1"></textarea><p class="v1">
<textarea id="txt2" class="txt2"></textarea><p class="v2">
<button onclick="translate ()"></button>

<script type="text/javascript">

x = document.getElementById('txt1').value;
y = document.getElementById('txt2').value;
y.innerHTML = x;

</script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```js
const x = document.getElementById('txt1');
const y = document.getElementById('txt2');
const btn = document.querySelector('button');

btn.onclick = () => {
  y.value = x.value;
  x.value = "";
}
```

```html
<div>
  <textarea id="txt1"></textarea>
  <textarea id="txt2"></textarea>
  <button>translate</button>
</div>
```

Comment: хорош ) ........Мог бы еще сократить код :)

Comment: @Избытоксусликов, впервые за которое время стало не лень ответить

Comment: может быть потому что вопрос не сложный .

Comment: Спасибо большое! Очень помог, просто делаю проект для школы, а это не мог сделать, спасибо!

Comment: @Избытоксусликов, ты прав, на сложный вопрос не хочется много времени тратить;)

Comment: @НикитаКраснобаев, всегда пожалуйста)

Comment: @Избытоксусликов неправда. Сложные вопросы - это всегда вызов и азарт, а простые... как камешек пнуть прогуливаясь)

Comment: @UModeL, верно, вызов, но лично у меня не всегда найдется время на сложные вопросы, по крайней мере пока что) “Вся наша жизнь – игра, а люди в ней – актеры”